# How do I select all the columns first cells (tds) in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2.12.  Using the WebDriver API, let's say I have a WebElement that represents a table (`<table>`).  Using that element, how do I select all the td's in the first column?  I'm assuming an xpath expression is in order here.

To better understand the table structure, if I get the HTML from my tableElement WebElement ...

```
String html = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", tableElt);
```

I get the jumble below.  The key thing to notice is that there are 6 tr's and 16 td's ...

```
<thead><tr><th colspan="1" class="GCSPOWVGE GCSPOWVEE GCSPOWVEF GCSPOWVFF"><div style="padding-left: 17px;position:relative;zoom:1;"><div style="left:0px;margin-top:-4px;position:absolute;top:50%;line-height:0px;"><img onload='this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";' src="http://localhost:9080/cme-productplus-web/productplus/clear.cache.gif" style="width: 11px; height: 7px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAHCAYAAADebrddAAAAiklEQVR42mNgwALyKrumFRf3iDAQAvmVXVVAxf/zKjq341WYV95hk1fZ+R+MK8C4HqtCkLW5FZ2PQYpyK6AaKjv/5VV1OmIozq3s3AFR0AXFUNMrO5/lV7WKI6yv6mxCksSGDyTU13Mw5JV2qeaWd54FWn0BRAMlLgPZl/NAuBKMz+dWdF0H2hwCAPwcZIjfOFLHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat 0px 0px;" border="0"></div><div>GUID</div></div></th><th colspan="1" class="GCSPOWVGE GCSPOWVEF">Fung Ratio</th><th colspan="1" class="GCSPOWVGE GCSPOWVEF">Fung type</th><th colspan="1" class="GCSPOWVGE GCSPOWVEF">Fung Date Offset</th><th colspan="1" class="GCSPOWVGE GCSPOWVEF  GCSPOWVOE">Days To Retain</th></tr></thead><colgroup><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup><tbody><tr onclick="" class="GCSPOWVAE"><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE GCSPOWVCE"><div style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">      DSSUAQR6IE6E    </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">      10      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">              </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE GCSPOWVME"><div style="outline:none;">            </div></td></tr><tr onclick="" class="GCSPOWVAF"><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBF GCSPOWVCE"><div style="outline:none;">      ETTUAQR6IE6E    </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBF"><div style="outline:none;">      30      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBF"><div style="outline:none;">              </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBF"><div style="outline:none;">      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBF GCSPOWVME"><div style="outline:none;">            </div></td></tr><tr onclick="" class="GCSPOWVAE"><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE GCSPOWVCE"><div style="outline:none;">      FCCUAQR6IE6E    </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">      20      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">              </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE"><div style="outline:none;">      </div></td><td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE GCSPOWVME"><div style="outline:none;">            </div></td></tr></tbody><tbody style="display: none;"><tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><div><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"></div></div><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;"><div class="GCSPOWVPE" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"><img class="gwt-Image" onload='this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";' src="http://localhost:9080/cme-productplus-web/productplus/clear.cache.gif" style="width: 43px; height: 11px; background: url(data:image/gif;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;" border="0"></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody><tfoot style="display: none;"><tr><th colspan="5" class="GCSPOWVFE GCSPOWVDE  GCSPOWVNE"></th></tr></tfoot>
```

Sadly, both these expressions do not yield the correct results.

```
        // This returns zero td's
        final List<WebElement> tds = tableElt.findElements(By.xpath("/tr/td[1]"));

        ...

        // This returns 238 td's (I think that's everything in my document)
        final List<WebElement> tds = tableElt.findElements(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>     // This returns 238 td's (I think that's everything in my document)               
>     final List<WebElement> tds = tableElt.findElements(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
> ```

This is exactly as per thw XPath W3c Spec and is one of the most FAQ in XPath.

The precedence (priority) of the `//` pseudo-operator is less than that of the `[]` operator.

Therefore, `//SomeName[1]` selects all elements named `SomeName` that are the first `SomeName` child of their parent -- and there may be many such elements.

If you want to select the 1st `SomeName` element in the XML document, you need to explicitly override the default operator precedence using brackets:

```
(//SomeName)[1]
```

In this case you only want the first `td` descendant of a given element -- therefore in addition to the above correction, you must correct your expression to be *relative* -- not absolute. An absolute XPath expression (starting with `/` is always evaluated having as aditional context node the document node).

**Use**:

```
(.//td)[1]
```

If you need all `td` descendants of the current node selected, then use:

```
.//td
```

And even better:

```
.//descendant::td
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far.  The expression (.//td)[1] only returns the first td cell, as opposed to all cells in the first column, which is what I want.  Thanks, -

Comment: @Dave: Oh, then just use: `.//td`

Comment: Thanks for continuing to stick with this, but the answer that actually worked for me was "(.//td[1])".  Doesn't your answer only return a single element?

Comment: @Dave: Re: `(.//td[1])` . The brackets don't matter and you may just ommit them. This selects any `td` descendant that is the first `td` child of its parent. You didn't explain in your question that you actually wanted that. Also, it still isn't clear which is the initial context node (down from which you are looking for `td` s. This all is a concequence from the fact that you didn't provied a sample source XML document. It would be nice if you edit your question and provide all this missing and essential information. I hope that your questions' quality will improve in the future.

Comment: @Dave: And about my answer "returning onlly a single node" -- you obviously didn't read the update. `.//td` *selects* all `td` descendants of the initial context node.

Comment: Unless someone edited my question, I did provide a sample -- there should be something starting with "<thead><tr><th ..." in my question.  Maybe what I'm using is "working" even though its not what I want.  Again, what I was looking for is the first td per column.  So, in the provided code, there should be four tbody columns, and I would expect to have four td cells.  Again, I appreciate your help and am open to suggestions as how to phrase the question better.

Answer (score 5):

The exact expression to use depends on the actual structure of your document.

In the most general case -- selecting all of the first-column cells from a table -- you could use the following expression:

```
<path_to_table>//td[1]
```

For example, on this document:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>ii</td>
        <td>iii</td>
        <td>iv</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This expression:

```
/table//td[1]
```

Gives:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>i</td>
```

Note that I'm using the descendant-or-self axis (`//`) because HTML tables allow optional grouping elements (e.g. `<tbody>`), which may or may not be there. However, this will include the first-column cells from nested tables, as well. Consider this input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><table><td>test</td></table></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>ii</td>
        <td>iii</td>
        <td>iv</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The same expression from above returns:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>i</td>
```

If you know more about your specific table structure, then you can write a more specific expression. For example, on the previous input, this expression:

```
/table/tr/td[1]
```

...returns only cells from the outermost table:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>i</td>
```

Comment: What is the expression I would need to write if I have a WebElement that already points at the table in question?  So, it would be something like tableElement.findElement(By.xpath("...")) Thanks, - Dave

Comment: @Dave - In that case it's probably something like `/tr/td[1]` or `//td[1]`, depending on the table structure

Comment: Hi, Sadly each of those expressions fails to get the correct results.  I edited my response to include the table structure from my WebElement.  Although it is a mess, take my word that the first expression (/tr/td[1]) returns zero elements when calling, "final List<WebElement> tds = tableElt.findElements(By.xpath("/tr/td[1]"));".  The second returns 238, which is every td in my HTML document, as opposed to only the td's within the table element.

Comment: I don't know Selenium, but it looks to me like the XPath isn't being evaluated relative to the table.

Comment: If you've already got the table element then it would be as easy as tableElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

Comment: Sam, per my question, I'm not looking for all table cells, only those in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

If each `tr` contains equal number of `td` you can form a list of all the `td` elements using `.findElements(By.tagName("td"))` and iterate through every nth element of that list where n is equal to the number of `td` elements in each `tr`

```
List<WebElement> allTDs = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
int n = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();

List<WebElement> yourTDs = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for (int i = 0; i < allTDs.size(); i = i + n){
    yourTDs.add(allTDs.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I'm with this guy. The code may not work as such but you get the idea.
Get all td or tr elements and work with them in your java code which is quite fast in contrast to to xpath.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the table stored as a WebElement then all you need to do is parse the WebElement just like you would the WebDriver.

```
//The first part is just a reference for others to see the table element being caught
WebElement TableElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
```

This will create a list of the td elements (you should use the xpath as you can specify the relative xPath of the element and state which specific element you want the xPath tends to be a little on the slow side so if you are parsing a large page you may want to go with CssSelector :first-of-type

```
List<WebElement> FirstColumns = TableElement.findElements(By.xPath("//tr/td[1]"));
```