# forEach loop in BPEL (WSO2 BPS)

Tags: wso2, bpel

I am not able to figure out the root cause for the problem, why the forEach loop is not working,

```
<bpel:forEach name="eachMarket" parallel="no" counterName="marketCounter">
                            <bpel:startCounterValue>1</bpel:startCounterValue>
                            <bpel:finalCounterValue>count($input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID)</bpel:finalCounterValue>
                            <bpel:scope>
                                <bpel:assign>
                                    <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" insertMissingToData="yes">
                                        <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/tns:DEFTYPE</bpel:from>
                                        <bpel:to>$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:DCTIDs/ns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/ns:DEFTYPE</bpel:to>
                                    </bpel:copy>
                                    <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" insertMissingToData="yes">
                                        <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/tns:MarketName</bpel:from>
                                        <bpel:to>$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:DCTIDs/ns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/ns:MarketName</bpel:to>
                                    </bpel:copy>
                                    <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" insertMissingToData="yes">
                                        <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/tns:DCTID</bpel:from>
                                        <bpel:to>$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:DCTIDs/ns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/ns:DCTID</bpel:to>
                                    </bpel:copy>
                                </bpel:assign>
                            </bpel:scope>
                        </bpel:forEach>
                        <bpel:forEach name="eachParameter" parallel="no" counterName="parameterCounter">
                            <bpel:startCounterValue>1</bpel:startCounterValue>
                            <bpel:finalCounterValue>count($input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:AdditionalParamters/tns:Parameter)</bpel:finalCounterValue>
                            <bpel:scope name="parameterScope">
                                <bpel:assign>
                                    <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" insertMissingToData="yes">
                                        <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:AdditionalParamters/tns:Parameter[$parameterCounter]/tns:Name</bpel:from>
                                        <bpel:to>$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:AdditionalParamters/ns:Parameter[$parameterCounter]/ns:Name</bpel:to>
                                    </bpel:copy>
                                    <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes" insertMissingToData="yes">
                                        <bpel:from>$input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:AdditionalParamters/tns:Parameter[$parameterCounter]/tns:Value</bpel:from>
                                        <bpel:to>$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:AdditionalParamters/ns:Parameter[$parameterCounter]/ns:Value</bpel:to>
                                    </bpel:copy>
                                </bpel:assign>
                            </bpel:scope>
                        </bpel:forEach>
```

Input will contain multiple Ids,

```
    <p:DCTIDs>
        <p:DCTID>
            <p:DEFTYPE>acvinclis</p:DEFTYPE>
            <p:MarketName>pectoreflammas</p:MarketName>
            <p:DCTID>3</p:DCTID>
        </p:DCTID>
        <p:DCTID>
            <p:DEFTYPE>acvinclis</p:DEFTYPE>
            <p:MarketName>pectoreflammas</p:MarketName>
            <p:DCTID>3</p:DCTID>
        </p:DCTID>
        <p:DCTID>
            <p:DEFTYPE>acvinclis</p:DEFTYPE>
            <p:MarketName>pectoreflammas</p:MarketName>
            <p:DCTID>3</p:DCTID>
        </p:DCTID>
    </p:DCTIDs>
```

Error message:
faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: No results for expression: '$OrderParameterPLRequest.parameters/ns:DCTResponse/ns:DCTIDs/ns:DCTID[round($marketCounter)]/ns:DEFTYPE' against '

Comment: Now I am getting a different error

Comment: Now I am getting a different error Assignment Fault: selectionFailure: R-Value expression "{OXPath10Expression $input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID[$Counter]/tns:DEFTYPE}" returned multiple.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN}/bps/ProcessOrder}ReportProcessWorkFlow-55 has completed with fault: FaultData: [faultName={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure, faulType=null ({ $input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID[$Counter]/tns:DEFTYPE}" returned multiple nodes.)]

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably not relevant for the original poster anymore, but I wanted to include an answer in case anybody else has the same problem.

If you want to get the DEFTYPE of the DCTID at position $Counter, use the following XPath:

```
($input.payload/tns:DCTResponse/tns:DCTIDs/tns:DCTID)[position() = $Counter]/tns:DEFTYPE
```

Two things are important here:

- Put parentheses around the entire expression up to DTCID. For the reason why, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336922/5986352
- While [1], [2], etc. will work, [$Counter] will not work. Instead, use [position() = $Counter]. You can also use position() to perform some more complex queries, e.g., [position() < 3] in order to select the first two nodes from a certain set.